# Dataset, use list as header

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, dataset

I have a dataset with a header for row and column which consists of binaries, e.g.:

```
cols = ToString /@ IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3]
rows = ToString /@ IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3]
tbl = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}

data = Dataset[AssociationThread[rows, tbl]][All, 
  AssociationThread[cols, Range[Length[cols]]]]
```

Now I would like to extract parts of the matrix by a pattern, e.g. row: {1,0,_} and column: {__,0,0}
for the full binary this works:

```
data[ToString[{0, 0, 0}]][ToString[{1, 0, 0}]]
```

But now I would like to extract patterns like _,0,0 
How can this be done? Is their a way to use a list as header for row and column instead of strings?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use strings instead of the lists, I would say it is a bit awkward.  But it is possible.

```
data = Dataset[AssociationThread[rows, tbl]][All, 
  AssociationThread[cols, Range[Length[cols]]]]
rowheaders = Keys@Normal@data
colheaders = Keys@Normal@data[[1]]
matchedrows = 
 Select[rowheaders, 
  StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression["{0, 0, \\d}"]] &]
matchedcols = 
 Select[colheaders, 
  StringMatchQ[#, RegularExpression["{\\d, 0, 1}"]] &]
data[matchedrows, matchedcols]
```

Note that I chose selections that give a non-empty set of results, that these selections are based on regular expressions, and that we need to notice the presence of spaces in the string representations of the lists.

Comment: thanks @Alan. Actually I must not use strings, but I when I use lists it gives me a strange representation of the dataset: `cols = IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3] rows = IntegerDigits[Range[3], 2, 3] tbl = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}} data = Dataset[AssociationThread[rows, tbl]][All, AssociationThread[cols, Range[Length[cols]]]]`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `KeySelect` and `StringMatchQ`.

With `data` as in OP with string keys.

```
data
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
data[
 KeySelect[StringMatchQ[RegularExpression["{0, 1, \\d}"]]],
 KeySelect[StringMatchQ[RegularExpression["{\\d, 1, \\d}"]]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.